# PHP, distinguish between internal and external class method call

Tags: php, class, methods

Can't get my head around this, is there any way to check if a method was called internally? By this I mean a traceback to check if it was called by $this and not a pointer to the instance. Kind of like the concept of private function but only function is public?

```
<?php

class Foo {
    public function check () {
        /*
        if invoked by $this (internally)
            return true
        else
            return false
        */
    }

    public function callCheck () {
        /* returns true because its called by $this */
        return $this->check();
    }
}

$bar = new Foo;
// this should return false because we are calling it from an instance
$bar->check();
// where as this will return true
$bar->callCheck();

?>
```

Maybe this is undo-able but I really need it for my project at university? Anyone come across a solution or knows how I would identify a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like you should rather rework your interfaces. A function should not react differently depending on *how* it's called. If you're looking for `public`/`private` behavior, why not use it?

Comment: Why do you want to know the difference?  It seems likely that you're trying to solve a problem with the wrong solution.

Comment: @deceze @Jonah I'm trying to merge objects together, BUT keeping them apart. So I can programmatically extend objects rather than define it in the interface. So if a object has a protected function, the object that merged it can call the protected function, but obviously protected means you can call it from an instance? do you get me???

Comment: Maybe you should try something less awkward and use already established design patterns instead for whatever actual problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Adapter pattern [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)

Answer (score 1):

Below solution does not work.

---

You could use [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) but it will be slow. I really advise you find a different way to solve the problem you are trying to overcome.

```
<?php
public function check() {
    $trace = debug_backtrace();
    if ($trace[1]['class'] == 'MyClassName') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: the problem with the backtrace work around is that $bar class_name is equal to $this class_name so how does the method know who's calling it when the classes are equal.

Comment: You are right. I had thought class would be calling class, not the called class. Makes sense now that I think about it though.

Comment: The instance and class are the same you see, the class does not inherit or extend interfaces

Answer (score 0):

if you there is a call $bar->callCheck(); control exits from function check();

first it go to 
callCheck() then after it goest to check() and return from there

Answer (score 0):

debug_backtrace(); should work. place the debug_backtrace(); inside check() method.

do this:

$t = debug_backtrace();
var_dump($t);

from here you should check $t['function'] and $t['class'], combine those 2 , you should find out is a call, external or internal.

here is out put from my machine, php version is 5.2.14.

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(7) {
    ["file"]=>
    string(15) "C:\php\test.php"
    ["line"]=>
    int(24)
    ["function"]=>
    string(5) "check"
    ["class"]=>
    string(3) "Foo"
    ["object"]=>
    object(Foo)#1 (0) {
    }
    ["type"]=>
    string(2) "->"
    ["args"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(7) {
    ["file"]=>
    string(15) "C:\php\test.php"
    ["line"]=>
    int(18)
    ["function"]=>
    string(5) "check"
    ["class"]=>
    string(3) "Foo"
    ["object"]=>
    object(Foo)#1 (0) {
    }
    ["type"]=>
    string(2) "->"
    ["args"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(7) {
    ["file"]=>
    string(15) "C:\php\test.php"
    ["line"]=>
    int(26)
    ["function"]=>
    string(9) "callCheck"
    ["class"]=>
    string(3) "Foo"
    ["object"]=>
    object(Foo)#1 (0) {
    }
    ["type"]=>
    string(2) "->"
    ["args"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but it kept returning true? Maybe you could help me out in the selection algorithm? I want to go back just 1 stack in the traceback not 2. The point I'm trying to make is who called check(); NOT who called callCheck(); then called check(); I can't find a solid way to do this, I'm looking into runkit extension maybe I'll play about with that and see if I can achieve the same goal in a different approach. Cheers!

Comment: in array(1), there is only one element, which indicate, "check()" is called by itself, that is an external call. in Array(2), there are 2 sub arrays inside, and check() is top one, which indicate the "check()" was called by an other function, check that function we found out the function comes from same class which "check()" belongs to , so this means, the "check()" was be called internal

Comment: so Algorithm is: if there is one element in an array, it is a external call. if more than one, check the next element , if the next element has same class as the "check()" , it is an internal call, if the class diff, external call.