# Selectivley expose functions based on external or internal calls to methods

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, yii, encapsulation

This question closely resembles what I'm trying to achieve, but as has been indicated in excruciating detail in almost every answer to the question, it is bad-design.

> [PHP, distinguish between internal and external class method call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428297/php-distinguish-between-internal-and-external-class-method-call)

**Here's what I'm trying to achieve:**
Track all actions performed on low-activity configuration tables so that the changes can be propagated to production and QA databases. (configuration tables = Configuration is stored in tables.)

**Here's a synopsis of my problem:**
All models in Yii extend from the CActiveRecord class which provides some methods to manipulate instances of Models.

Let's break these into 2 categories:

1. **Non-Primitives** - Which trigger events like onBeforeDelete, onAfterFind, onAfterSave etc. (ex: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.13/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php#L1061)
2. **Primitives** - Which directly create and execute commands without triggering events - i.e. act as query generators. (ex: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.13/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php#L1684)

Now, these primitives are also public members and thus can be called from outside the class at the users' discretion - *And they will modify the table without triggering any events.*

**These are the solutions I have come up with:**

1. Lay down guidelines for all developers to use Non-primitive methods only.
2. Encapsulate CActiveRecord in my own model class and expose only non-primitives.

**Case 1** will be easier to implement but will be more error prone since at some time some developer might forget the restriction and use a primitive method.

**Case 2** will require me to write a lot of code / methods exposing methods I wish to be used. Also, this might cause confusion if both the Yii CActiveRecord and my ActiveRecord class don't have the same interface.

A better solution, in my opinion will be to allow usage of primitives internally while restricting external calls, i.e. using the private/public access specifiers. (This is already contradicted by the reason I provided in case 2, but this is the only solution I can come up with.) Since I cannot use private/public specifiers without encapsulating, and I cannot encapsulate, I'd like to distinguish within the method whether the function is an external call or an internal. **debug_backtrace** is a viable solution, but I'm here for a more elegant, less hacky solution, or a definitive statement that this cannot be done.

Comment: Although the question might be interesting it suites better for http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @hek2mgl, I wasn't a member of programmers.stackexchange.com until you mentioned, thanks for that, I'll look into it.

Comment: Yeah, I assume you'll get better answers there. Also I would add some explaining code to the question.

Comment: I couldn't get the code to highlight properly so I instead referenced to the code via github links, my extension of the CActiveRecord class would not be relevant to the question thus I didn't post it.

Comment: now I see the github links :)

Comment: If I can give a general advice: `Lay down guidelines for all developers to use Non-primitive methods only.` This will not work, as developers will not do this. Especially when deadlines happen. (it's my experience) Also you'll ending up reminding them about guidelines again and again. (what can be annoying for both sites) I would search for an *automatic* solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should take a step back and think about *why* there is such a difference in behavior. The methods you call non-primitive are supposed to be called on a model instance:

```
$ar = new Something();
$ar->update(...);
```

While the methods you call primitive are supposed to be called on *the* model itself:

```
Something::model()->updateByPk(...);
```

It stands to reason that it doesn't make sense to raise events in the second case because

1. you are not supposed to work directly with `::model()` at all, and
2. depending on the method, the operation can affect multiple records for which there are no corresponding model instances in PHP

So the quest for a solution should start with you answering these two questions:

1. In a perfect world, how would you be notified when calling any method on the model? (Obviously the method would need to be primitive for the call to make sense).
2. In a perfect world, how would you be notified of an operation that affects an unknown (in PHP) number of records?

Comment: I understand what you meant by "you are not supposed to work directly with `::model()`", but I need a method to enforce this.  Also, an ideal place to do this is on the database layer using triggers - I'll fallback to this if I can't find a solution - All I want from this question is assurance that there is no possible way to accomplish this within Yii.

Comment: @AdeelHasanAkbari: You cannot enforce this in any sane way. You are not supposed to touch the static model, so just don't. It's not like you can make a typo and write `Foo::model()` when you really meant `new Foo()`. Also, I have posted a couple of counter questions that you need to answer. If you cannot even answer "how would you like this to work" then obviously it will never work.

Comment: Since you're also a programming teacher, I'll take this as an exercise and answer your questions to the best of my capability, I hope you'll be patient with me if I falter.
1. Programmatically, I would use the magic method `__call()` after encapsulating to learn what methods are being called on the model.
2. I can analyze the query generated as a result of the operation - query parser, or go the easier, more reliable way and use triggers to track changes.

Comment: @AdeelHasanAkbari: I don't mean how they would be implemented -- I mean how would you like them to be exposed? In other words, suppose that this feature exists and magically works exactly how you want. What would the code that *uses* it look like?

Comment: I get it now ... It would at best be awkward. A piece of code that morphs/adapts based on how you interact with it would be somewhat confusing. Thank you for causing me to think! I suppose the best solution would be DB Triggers.